# Как добавить значениям массива обратные кавычки?

Tags: php

Как добавить всем значениям массива вот такие кавычки `` ?

На данный момент массив со значениями выглядит так:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => test2
)
```

А нужно, чтобы они были такие:

```
`test`
`test2`
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не выкладывайте скрины кода, оформляйте как текст

Comment: @АлексейШиманский **[offtop]** _вы, оказывается, бас-гитарист? ) В таком случае мы с вами коллеги! :)_ **[/offtop]**

Comment: "одни гитаристы в стране" ©

Comment: @Эдуард на самом деле я электрогитарист (соло). Бас - разве что сессионник . Просто фотка с басом классная)

Comment: а видели [такую вакансию то](https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/about/jobs.htm)? @АлексейШиманский, Эдуард :D я что-то вообще не знал, что сайт нашего происхождения  :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский давно занимаетесь музыкой? Если говорить обо мне - мне сорок один год, и я уже почти не занимаюсь _(очень редко)_ . Но лет двадцать назад был в тройке лучших басистов своего города _(Сумы)_ . Техника конечно не супер, но если два-три дня "погонять" гаммы - быстро восстанавливается :)

Comment: @teran да, я лично видел. И даже пробовал к ним отправлять резюмеху _(покуда не был ещё трудоустроен)_ Но у них нужно работать с высоконагруженными проектами. У меня подобного опыта нет, и поэтому я устроился в другую компанию, поддержка инет магазина.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

как то так?

```
$result = array_map(function($v){ return "`$v`"; }, $data)
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает